# unable to git commit and push as another user

Tags: git, hook

I am trying to run git commands as another user on the same computer named `testuser`. I have set the global username and email to `testuser` and `testuser@email.com`. I have also set the commit.name and commit.email to the same username/email in hopes of having the committer name and author name be the same. When I try to push the changes, I get the following message:

```
remote: You can only push your own commits in this repository
remote: Commit 1234567890 was committed by testuser <testuser@email.com
! [remote rejected] head -> main (pre-receive hook declined).
```

Unfortunately, I am unable to disable this "Verify Committer" hook in bitbucket due to policy, so I need to find a way around it.
I know this has something to do with the committer name and author name being mismatched but I don't see a mismatch anywhere so I'm lost.

I have tried these commands:

```
git config --global user.name "testuser"
git config --global user.name "testuser@email.com"
git config --global commit.name "testuser"
git config --global commit.name "testuser@email.com"
```

some other trials looked like:

```
git add --all
git -c user.name="testuser" -c user.email="testuser@email.com" commit --author="testuser <testuser@email.com>" -m "message"
git push -u origin head:main --force --no-verify
```

and more drastically:

```
git filter-branch --env-filter '
export GIT_AUTHOR_NAME="testuser"
export GIT_AUTHOR_EMAIL="testuser@email.com"
export GIT_COMMITTER_NAME="testuser"
export GIT_COMMITTER_EMAIL="testuser@email.com"
' --tag-name-filter cat -- --branches --tags
```

all with no luck, ultimately returning the same pre-receive hook error.
I've also tried removing the git windows credentials in credential manager.

Comment: Where are you pushing these changes?

Comment: Well, apparently, "testuser" is not your username or email. You need to set the correct one (probably to be found out by comparing to the email configured in BitBucket?)

Comment: @JimRedmond I am pushing these changes into a bitbucket repository. I cannot link it due to security reasons.

Comment: @knittl that's the point. I don't want to push these changes as myself. I want to push them as the other user on my computer named "testuser". I'll check bitbucket to see if the "testuser" name and email has been set up properly there.

Comment: Whoever set up this rule probably had a reason for it. Best to talk to them.

Comment: @knittl that's the fun part, we have no idea who done it nor are we ever going to get it disabled in any circumstances. Love red tape

Comment: I ruled out the author name and committer name mismatch with the following command: `git cat-file commit <commit-hash>`. this shows the committer name and author name of the chosen hash. I believe my issue lies within bitbucket and how the user was set up there.

Comment: in my case, the issue was with how the bitbucket user was set up. It did not have an email attached to it so it was rejecting every push I tried to make. It's fixed now.